# How to define a type based on the array type of an existing type, in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

There is already a type:

```
type Group = {
  name: string,
  users: {
    name: string,
    email: string
  }[]
}
```

Now I want to define a new type `User` based on the `Group['users']`, but I'm not sure how to do it:

```
type User = ???(Group['users'])
```

the type `User` should have exactly the structure of: `{name:string, email:string}`.

Is there any way to extract the item type from an array type?

Comment: `Group['users'][number]`

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) for documentation... the type `string[][0]` is just `string`, as is `string[][number]`

Comment: Thanks, guys, can't believe it, it's so easy